# Two adverbs of time

Tags: commas, adverbs

Is the sentence:

> Did something happen yesterday after that (conversation)?

grammatically correct, or is a comma required after yesterday?

Comment: No number of commas, that, I put, absolut,ely anyw,,,,here in this sent,,,,ence,, can possibly change the fact that it is correct *grammatically*. They can make it harder to read. Or easier to read. And that is all they can possibly do.

Comment: Punctuationally (I looked it up!), the comma is optional. Use it (or a dash) to signal a pause if you want to add a bit of drama or to show that the PP is an afterthought; leave it out if you want the sentence read in uninterrupted fashion.